# Is there a way to target an element that gets added dynamically to the page in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to hack a solution to an iframe that gets added dynamically to my page in order to change its CSS. I have the iframe's id. Is there a way of doing this with React?

Edit: I'm using React. I don't have access to the source code of the iframe (an embedded checkout as part of an online shop) so can only make changes to its CSS once it's been dynamically added to the page.

Comment: Please elaborate, provide an example. What does this have to do with React?

Comment: @FelixKling with vanilla JS you could target the element by Id. I don't feel I can add much else pertinent detail unfortunately.

Comment: Well, as it is it's unclear how React is related to all this and what exactly you want to do with the iframe.

Comment: *"an embedded checkout as part of an online shop"* If the iframe is not served from the same server as the parent page, you cannot make any changes to it. It sounds like that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use React refs
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: To use a ref you need access to the actual element, do you not?

Comment: @mistarsv: To use a ref the element has to be created by React. Since you are not providing a lot of information about your situation it's really hard to make any suggestions.